# Why does "exit" not exit my script when I pipe it to "tee"?

Tags: bash, shell

I am running a script which is using `tee` to log the output to screen and also to a file:

```bash
{ echo "hello world" ; exit 1; } | tee -a logfile.log
```

The `exit` is not working. I can't exit my script. When I delete `tee`, it works. Why is that?

Comment: `exit` is working actually. Try `{ echo "hello world" ; exit 1; echo xyzzy; }| tee -a logfile.log` and you'll see that `xyzzy` won't be written to neither to stdout nor the file. In a construct like `command1 | command2`, each command  is executed in its own subshell. (The last command may be run in the current shell if the `lastpipe` option is enabled)

Comment: Why aren't you doing the `exit` as the next statement after your pipeline, when you want to exit the process which runs the pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As covered elsewhere (including, somewhat indirectly, [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)), pipelines create subshells, so your `exit` exits only the subshell.

You can avoid this by replacing the pipeline with a redirection to a process substitution:

```
{ echo "hello world"; exit 1; } > >(tee -a logfile.log)
```

Comment: It's working ! Thanks!  I'am never think redirection can do this.

Comment: but i also can't understand, in my script,  exit is befor the pipelines,  so why exit is  working in subshell or not  parent shell?

Comment: @linklin, when you put `{ echo "hello world"; exit 1; }` in braces _and pipe its output to something else_, that command group becomes a single pipeline element running in a single subshell; so exit exits that subshell (that is part of the pipeline), not the overall shell.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the pipeline spawns a subshell for each component, so the `exit` runs inside this new shell.

You should rewrite the script like:

```bash
echo "hello world" | tee -a logfile.log
exit 1
```

Comment: It's not the brackets that create a subshell, it's the `|` pipeline.

Comment: I've edited this to try to improve accuracy. (It's also not "a new bash instance" but a forked subshell; these are different insofar as `fork()`ing copies local variable and other state that's lost during the `execve()` syscall and thus not present in a truly new shell).